# What is the elevator pitch for the site?

Tags: discussion, content, promotion

You're talking to a fellow Raspberry Pi enthusiast, a stranger, or even a member of the Raspberry Pi foundation.  What is a brief description for the site?

Answer (score 7):

A community of enthusiasts asking and answering questions about Raspberry Pi hardware and software.

Comment: Added a simple, basic line based on the description of the site so I could add it to community wiki.

Comment: Accurate enough, but it lacks catchyness if you ask me :)

Comment: Yup.  I'm hoping with it added to community wiki someone can come up with something.

Comment: Should we stick "users and developers" in there? Our current FAQ has those terms, but honestly, enthusiasts has a nice ring to it.

Comment: Semantics doesn't matter too much for the "elevator pitch."  The purpose of this discussion is to concisely define the site.  From there, things like tag lines can be determined as per [this guide](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

Answer (score 1):

"It is a community driven question and answer website for the Raspberry Pi Computer."

Shamelessly ripped off from the wikipedia page for https://askubuntu.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ask_Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

A community-based question and answer site for users, developers, and researchers of Raspberry Pi.

`<shameless>`

...[Take a MegaByte!](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)

`</shameless>`

Comment: May cause some anger and/or [legal threats](http://www.raspberrypi.org/trademark-rules)

Answer (score 0):

There would be plenty of people who may not really know what a Raspberry Pi is, even if they've heard it mentioned. "Miniature computer" might be a good elevator description of it that's worth mentioning in there somewhere.

**A question-and-answer website for enthusiasts on how to use a Raspberry Pi miniature computer.**